# Is there a way to save regular HTML/CSS/JS as a php variable?

Tags: php, html, string, heredoc

I am familiar with HEREDOC, but that is not what I want to use.
What I was hoping for was a way to edit HTML/CSS in the PHP file so that it is not technically a string so that I can get proper HTML/CSS/JS hints and autocompletes in my text editor. When trying to edit inside HEREDOC it is considered a string so I do not get any hits, which causes a lot of syntax errors.
Something like this: (Like the use of the if statement brackets)

```
<?php
   $html='
?>

<style>
   h4{
      font-weight:700;
   }
</style>

<h4>HTML</h4>

<?php
   ';

echo $html;

?>
```

Is there a way to put the html/css in another file then include it inside a concat string?

```
<?php
   $html=''.include('html.php').'';
   echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you are simply looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php ? Write your HTML code outside of `<?php … ?>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) - in this simplified example you'd get the html from file `view.php` and you'd assign it to `$html`.

```
<?php
$html = getHtml('view.php');
echo $html;

function getHtml(string $file)
{
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

[`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) turns on output buffering
[`ob_get_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) gets current buffer contents (returns as string) and deletes current output buffer

Answer (score 0):

As far a PHP is concerned, HTML and JS is just text so you can store them in a PHP variable in the same way as you would store any string.

```php
$html = '<style>
   h4{
      font-weight:700;
   }
</style>

<h4>HTML</h4>';
```

To load HTML from a separate file into a variable, how you would do it depends on the file. If it contains PHP code that needs to be executed, then follow [jibsteroos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66173160/2453432) answer about [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

If the file doesn't contain any PHP, you can use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$html = file_get_contents('html.php');
```

***Note:** If `html.php` contains any PHP, it will be read as text instead of being executed.*